# How to add iOS 13.3 simulator to XCode 14.0.1 on MacOs 13 Ventura?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-ventura

I am having trouble finding the iOS 13.3 simulator on XCode after I updated my MacOS Version to 13.0 Ventura. The lowest available version to download is iOS 13.7, I need
anything at 13.3 or lower. Furthermore, looking through older posts about simulators missing. They all state that downloading simulators can be achieved by going to Preferences > Components, which my XCode does not have. Preferences seems to be renamed to Settings and there is no Components tab anywhere in the settings.

Any suggestions on how to get this done?

Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

Window > Devices and Simulators > Simulators

On the left is a list of installed Simulators
Each Simulator can be marked as "Show as run destination"
At the bottom-left is a "+" icon, to add new simulators

Simulator name
Device Type
OS Version
OS Version > Download more simulator runtimes...

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/695829

Comment: Yep, thats the process to install whatever simulators are available for my mac version. The lowest iOS version I am allowed to install currently is 13.7. [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/zWVeHdQ)

Comment: I am also having an issue currently. I can create a Simulator (iOS 13.7), select it to always show as run-destination. But it won't show up in the drop down menu. Any idea why?